# SetApprovalForAll: not owner nor approved

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, erc721

Hello to everyone i have a problem in my contracts and i don't understand how to solve it...Is a Nft Marketplace, and the problem happen on the second sale, i mean if i mint a token, then import the token in the markeplace and sell it from A to B is working....but if i try to sell from B to C i receive error "Caller not owner nor approved".

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract NFTS is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable{
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenId;

    address contractOwner;
    address marketPlace;

    constructor(address _marketplace)ERC721("AAA", "BBB"){
        marketPlace = _marketplace;
        contractOwner = msg.sender;
    }

    mapping(uint=>address) public tokenCreator;

    function createNFT(string memory _uri)external returns(uint){
        _tokenId.increment();
        uint newId = _tokenId.current();
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newId);
        _setTokenURI(newId, _uri);
        setApprovalForAll(marketPlace, true);
        tokenCreator[newId] = msg.sender;
        return newId;
    }
}





contract Marketplace is Ownable, ReentrancyGuard{
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _itemId;

    address payable contractOwner;
    uint listingPrice = 1 wei;
    uint delistingPrice = 1 wei;

    constructor(){
        contractOwner = payable(msg.sender);
    }


    struct importItemInMarketplace{
        address _nftContract;
        address payable contractOwner;
        address payable tokenCreator;
        address payable tokenOwner;
        address payable buyer;
        uint tokenId;
        uint price;
        uint royalties;
    }

    mapping(uint=>importItemInMarketplace) public idItemImportedInMarketplace;

    event successImported(
        address _nftContract,
        address payable contractOwner,
        address payable tokenCreator,
        address payable tokenOwner,
        address payable buyer,
        uint tokenId,
        uint price,
        uint royalties
    );


    struct itemForRoyalties{
        address payable contractOwner;
        address payable tokenCreator;
        uint price;
        uint royalties;
    }

    mapping(uint=>itemForRoyalties) public tokenIdRoyalties;


    function itemInMarketplace(
        address _nftContract,
        uint _tokenId,
        uint _price,
        uint _royalties
    )external payable nonReentrant{
        address tokenOwner = NFTS(_nftContract).ownerOf(_tokenId);
        address tokenCreator = NFTS(_nftContract).tokenCreator(_tokenId);
        
        require(_price > 0, "Cannot set a price less or equal to 0!");
        require(msg.value == listingPrice, "You have to pay 1 wei to list your token!");
        require(msg.sender == tokenOwner, "Cannot list a token if is not yours!" );
        require(_royalties > 5 && _royalties < 20, "You can set royalties between 5% and 20 % !");
        
        _itemId.increment();
        uint newId = _itemId.current();
        
        
        
        idItemImportedInMarketplace[newId] = importItemInMarketplace(
            _nftContract,
            payable(contractOwner),
            payable(tokenCreator),
            payable(tokenOwner),
            payable(address(0)),
            _tokenId,
            _price,
            _royalties  
        );
        
        
        tokenIdRoyalties[_tokenId] = itemForRoyalties(
            payable(contractOwner),
            payable(tokenCreator),
            _price,
            _royalties
        );

    }

    function getDataRoyalties(uint _tokenId)public view returns(
        address, address, uint, uint
    ){
        return (tokenIdRoyalties[_tokenId].contractOwner, tokenIdRoyalties[_tokenId].tokenCreator, tokenIdRoyalties[_tokenId].price, tokenIdRoyalties[_tokenId].royalties);
    }



    struct ItemSold{
        address _nftContract;
        address payable contractOwner;
        address payable tokenCreator;
        address payable prevTokenOwner;
        address payable buyer;
        uint tokenId;
        uint price;
        uint royalties;
    }

    mapping(uint=>ItemSold)public soldedItemTokenId;


    event SoldSuccess(
        address _nftContract,
        address payable contractOwner,
        address payable tokenCreator,
        address payable prevTokenOwner,
        address payable buyer,
        uint tokenId,
        uint price,
        uint royalties
    );



    function purchase(address _nftContract, uint _itemIds)external payable nonReentrant{
        address payable _contractOwner = idItemImportedInMarketplace[_itemIds].contractOwner;
        address payable _tokenOwner = idItemImportedInMarketplace[_itemIds].tokenOwner;
        address payable _tokenCreator = idItemImportedInMarketplace[_itemIds].tokenCreator;
        address payable _prevTokenOwner = _tokenOwner;
        address payable _buyer = idItemImportedInMarketplace[_itemIds].buyer;
        uint _tokenId = idItemImportedInMarketplace[_itemIds].tokenId;
        uint _price = idItemImportedInMarketplace[_itemIds].price;
        uint _royalties = idItemImportedInMarketplace[_itemIds].royalties;
        
        require(msg.sender != _contractOwner && msg.sender != _tokenOwner, "Admin or tokenOwner cannot buy this Item!");
        require(msg.value == _price, "Set the right price to buy it!");

        payable(_contractOwner).transfer(listingPrice);
        _tokenOwner = payable(msg.sender);
        payable(_prevTokenOwner).transfer(_price);
        _buyer = payable(_tokenOwner);
        NFTS(_nftContract).transferFrom(_prevTokenOwner, _buyer, _tokenId);
        delete(idItemImportedInMarketplace[_itemIds]);
        _itemId.decrement();

        soldedItemTokenId[_tokenId] = ItemSold(
            _nftContract,
            payable(_contractOwner),
            payable(_tokenCreator),
            payable(_prevTokenOwner),
            payable(_buyer),
            _tokenId,
            _price,
            _royalties
        );


        emit SoldSuccess(
            _nftContract,
            payable(_contractOwner),
            payable(_tokenCreator),
            payable(_prevTokenOwner),
            payable(_buyer),
            _tokenId,
            _price,
            _royalties
        );
    }
```

Now i don't understand why i receive this error because on the second sale, the B account, can list the token, and by listing function only the token owner can list the token.
Any help is appreciate...thanks a lot and have a nice day

Comment: how did you end up fixing it?

Comment: Hello @hammies i didn't see your question.

Answer (score 0):

When a user calls `SetApprovalForAll(marketplace, true)` in the NFTS contract, he gives permission to the marketplace to trade any of **his** NFTs minted using that contract.

Now when A transfers the NFT to B, the marketplace executes the order on A's behalf and since A called SetApprovalForAll while minting the token, the marketplace has the permission to transfer A's tokens and there are no issues.

Now when B tries to transfer the NFT to C, B hasn't yet given permission to the marketplace to transfer his tokens. So this part of the code inside your purchase function throws the error "Caller not owner nor approved"

```
NFTS(_nftContract).transferFrom(_prevTokenOwner, _buyer, _tokenId);
```

So to solve this, you have to find a way for B to call SetApprovalForAll from the frontend. You can do this when B is signing up to your website or before the token transfer occurs.

With ethers.js, it looks like this

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(nftAddress, NFT.abi, signer)  //signer is B
const isApprovedForAll = await contract.isApprovedForAll(signerAddress, marketplaceAddress)
if(!isApprovedForAll){
    await contract.setApprovalForAll(maketplaceAddress, true)
}
```